# setTimeout with IIFE is NOT asynchronous?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've found a strange behavior in the following JavaScript code:

```js
console.log('hi')

setTimeout(function(){
  console.log('there');
}(), 5000)

console.log('I am js');
```

**My expected output in the console is:** 
hi 
I am js 
there

**But it is showing me:** 
hi 
there 
I am js

Why is that? If we use an IIFE with setTimeout it does not go through event loop and tasks queue? Could anyone explain the above output? Thanks in advance.

Comment: ...and what does the first "I" in "IIFE" stand for?

Comment: IIFE stands for immediately-invoked function expression

Comment: The word "immediately" should clue you in to why your code isn't going to work.

Answer (score 4):

When you define the function, you are executing it in the same step, thus the console log is displayed.

```
function(){
  console.log('there');
}()
```

In this case, the argument that `setTimeout()` receives is the function return value, which is `undefined` in this case.

I read your code as:

```
console.log('hi')

var arg = function(){ console.log('there') }(); // arg receives undefined

setTimeout(arg, 5000) // where arg is undefined and not a function

console.log('I am js');
```

Now, if you had returned another function, it would execute in 5 seconds as expected.

```js
console.log('hi')
    
var arg = function(){ 
  console.log('there') 
  
  return function() {
     console.log('there again') 
  }
  
}(); // arg receives a function
    
setTimeout(arg, 5000) // where arg is a function
    
console.log('I am js');
```

Comment: Okay, thanks for your response. In this case does the setTimeout go through event-loop?

Comment: @BerozaPaul, I've updated my answer to show that setTimeout executes asynchronously even with an IIFE. The problem with your code is that it executes with a invalid input (undefined). In my example, if I return another function inside a IIFE, setTimeout will execute it just fine.